# How to verify payment in php

Tags: php, mysql, web, paypal, payment

I am making a website, on which candidates can apply for the competition.
But, a candidate can only apply, if he has paid the registration fee. So, when a user clicks on APPLY button on the website, he is directed to the payment form of the PayStack website, when he will do the payment, he will be redirected to the registration page.
So, my question is, how can I confirm, If the user has made the payment or not, and is eligible to apply.
Needs help with this.

**I am using PHP for backend**

Comment: Would you please show as a simple code of what you tried ?

Comment: Which part of the code?

Comment: I actually didn't write backend yet. I will write code to register candidates. I only want that, a candidate has to pay a fee in order to register. So, who clicks on the register button, he is redirected to the Paystack PAYMENT form to do the payment. When he will done payment, he will be redirected to registration page to apply. I only want to know how to do this payment process.

Comment: You should read your payment gateway documentations and see how they return you and you can verify with their response. Some of payment gateways allow to query payment details with payment id so you can use such endpoints to be sure if user paid the amount.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the Answer. I have never done these payments, can you help me with that?

Comment: @FaizanJallani of course we can. Just try starting something then comeback here with the code you have done. we will help you as far as we can.

Comment: you can start searching little by little try this https://www.tutspointer.com/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-php-source-code/

Answer (score 1):

For PayStack, you should include the official accept payment javascript which will trigger an event upon payment completion (this trigger will be fired irrespective of whether the payment is successful)

Note: I will insert into the db a record (with name, email, amount) for the payment first with a system generated "reference" (e.g. [date]-[random string]), then use the following HTML to accept payment:

HTML to accept payment

```
 <form id="paymentForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" id="email-address" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="amount">Amount</label>
    <input type="tel" id="amount" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="first-name" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="last-name" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-submit">
    <button type="submit" onclick="payWithPaystack()"> Pay </button>
  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://js.paystack.co/v1/inline.js"></script>
```

The js is like this:

```
const paymentForm = document.getElementById('paymentForm');
paymentForm.addEventListener("submit", payWithPaystack, false);
function payWithPaystack(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let handler = PaystackPop.setup({
    key: 'pk_test_xxxxxxxxxx', // Replace with your public key
    email: document.getElementById("email-address").value,
    amount: document.getElementById("amount").value * 100,
    ref: ''+Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1), // generates a pseudo-unique reference. Please replace with a reference you generated. Or remove the line entirely so our API will generate one for you
    // label: "Optional string that replaces customer email"
    onClose: function(){
      alert('Window closed.');
    },
    callback: function(response){
      let message = 'Payment complete! Reference: ' + response.reference;
      alert(message);
    }
  });
  handler.openIframe();
}
```

Please make sure that the ref above is using [date]-[random string] generated previously.

Note: upon completion of the payment step, the callback event will be triggered.

Of course you will not want to "alert the message" in the callback, you should call (say by ajax) to a PHP which fires CURL to "verify/check" the status of the payment . A typical CRUL is like this:

```
curl https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/:reference
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY"
-X GET
```

If you implement the curl in PHP, it will be like this:

```
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/:reference');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Now the $result returned by the above CURL will be like one of the following:

Case 1: Successful

```
{
  "status": true,
  "message": "Verification successful",
  "data": {
    "amount": 27000,
    "currency": "NGN",
    "transaction_date": "2016-10-01T11:03:09.000Z",
    "status": "success",
    "reference": "DG4uishudoq90LD",
    "domain": "test",
    "metadata": 0,
    "gateway_response": "Successful",
    "message": null,
    "channel": "card",
    "ip_address": "41.1.25.1",
    "log": {
      "time_spent": 9,
      "attempts": 1,
      "authentication": null,
      "errors": 0,
      "success": true,
      "mobile": false,
      "input": [],
      "channel": null,
      "history": [{
        "type": "input",
        "message": "Filled these fields: card number, card expiry, card cvv",
        "time": 7
        },
        {
          "type": "action",
          "message": "Attempted to pay",
          "time": 7
        },
        {
          "type": "success",
          "message": "Successfully paid",
          "time": 8
        },
        {
          "type": "close",
          "message": "Page closed",
          "time": 9
        }
      ]
    }
    "fees": null,
    "authorization": {
      "authorization_code": "AUTH_8dfhjjdt",
      "card_type": "visa",
      "last4": "1381",
      "exp_month": "08",
      "exp_year": "2018",
      "bin": "412345",
      "bank": "TEST BANK",
      "channel": "card",
      "signature": "SIG_idyuhgd87dUYSHO92D",
      "reusable": true,
      "country_code": "NG",
      "account_name": "BoJack Horseman"
    },
    "customer": {
      "id": 84312,
      "customer_code": "CUS_hdhye17yj8qd2tx",
      "first_name": "BoJack",
      "last_name": "Horseman",
      "email": "bojack@horseman.com"
    },
    "plan": "PLN_0as2m9n02cl0kp6",
    "requested_amount": 1500000
  }
}
```

Case 2: Payment failed

```
{  
  "status":true,
  "message":"Verification successful",
  "data": {  
    "amount":27000,
    "currency":"NGN",
    "transaction_date":"2016-10-01T11:03:09.000Z",
    "status":"failed",
    "reference":"djfoidjkdkj41",
    "domain":"test",
    "metadata":0,
    "gateway_response":"Insufficient Funds",
    "message":null,
    "channel":"card",
    "ip_address":"41.1.25.1",
    "log": {  
      "time_spent":9,
      "attempts":1,
      "authentication":null,
      "errors":0,
      "success":true,
      "mobile":false,
      "input":[ ],
      "channel":null,
      "history": [  
         {  
           "type":"input",
           "message":"Filled these fields: card number, card expiry, card cvv",
           "time":7
         },
         {  
           "type":"action",
           "message":"Attempted to pay",
           "time":7
         },
         {  
           "type":"close",
           "message":"Page closed",
           "time":9
         }
      ]
    },
    "fees":null,
    "authorization":{  
      "authorization_code":"AUTH_8dfhjjdt",
      "card_type":"visa",
      "last4":"1381",
      "exp_month":"08",
      "exp_year":"2018",
      "bin":"412345",
      "bank":"TEST BANK",
      "channel":"card",
      "signature": "SIG_idyuhgd87dUYSHO92D",
      "reusable":true,
      "country_code":"NG",
      "account_name": "BoJack Horseman"
    },
    "customer":{  
      "id":84312,
      "customer_code":"CUS_hdhye17yj8qd2tx",
      "first_name":"BoJack",
      "last_name":"Horseman",
      "email":"bojack@horseman.com"
    },
    "plan":""
  }
}
```

Case 3: Invalid

```
{  
  "status":false,
  "message":"Invalid key"
}
```

So you should , rely on the status of the CURL return, update your db (e.g. if the data status is "success", update your db table's transaction record as "PAID") according to the transaction "reference".

Finally, if the data status is "success", please redirect the user page to your competition page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But, I have provided the user the link to PayStack's own made form. I didn't make my own.
This is a link to that form,  https://paystack.com/pay/missuniversalafrica
Here, the user will make payment. I want that when the user makes the payment, he should be redirected to the Registration Form, which is made by me and the further process takes place.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a url that you want the customer to be redirected to after payment is made on the Payment Page. Have you tried setting a value in the "Redirect after payment" text field?

https://support.paystack.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009881560-How-do-I-collect-one-time-payments-with-Payment-Pages-